# Microsoft Nano Server Preview 5 can't format the partition

Tags: windows-nano-server

I am trying to install Windows Nano server CTP5 following the guide MS posted [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt126167.aspx).

And I get the following error.

> PS E:\Nano\NanoServerImageGenerator> New-NanoServerImage -Edition Standard -DeploymentType Guest -MediaPath F:\ -BasePat
>   h e:\Nano\Base -TargetPath e:\Nano\NanoServerIIS.vhd -ComputerName NanoServerIIS -Packages Microsoft-NanoServer-IIS-Pack
>   age,Microsoft-NanoServer-DSC-Package
>
> cmdlet New-NanoServerImage at command pipeline position 1
>   Supply values for the following parameters:
>   AdministratorPassword: ********
>
> Windows(R) Image to Virtual Hard Disk Converter for Windows(R) 10
>   Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>   Version 10.0.14300.1000.amd64fre.rs1_release_svc.160324-1723
>
> INFO   : Looking for the requested Windows image in the WIM file
>   INFO   : Image 1 selected (ServerStandardNano)...
>   INFO   : Creating sparse disk...
>   INFO   : Mounting VHD...
>   INFO   : Initializing disk...
>   INFO   : Creating single partition...
>   INFO   : Formatting windows volume...
>   Format-Volume : Invalid Parameter
>   Activity ID: {e5829a32-da8d-41b5-9596-9a5d74620c46}
>   At E:\Nano\NanoServerImageGenerator\Convert-WindowsImage.ps1:1908 char:22
>   + ... temVolume = Format-Volume -Partition $systemPartition -FileSystem NTF ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (StorageWMI:ROOT/Microsoft/...age/MSFT_Volume) [Format-Volume], CimExce
>      ption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StorageWMI 5,Format-Volume
>
> ERROR  : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Volume'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, a
>   nd then try running the command again.
>   INFO   : Log folder is C:\Users\cdjambov\AppData\Local\Temp\Convert-WindowsImage\97ee34bd-35f1-4151-b35e-252be2a483e1
>   INFO   : Closing Windows image...
>   INFO   : Done.
>   WARNING: Terminating due to an error. See log file at:
>   C:\Users\cdjambov\AppData\Local\Temp\NanoServerImageGenerator.log
>   The requested image could not be created. Please consult the command output for additional information.
>   At E:\Nano\NanoServerImageGenerator\NanoServerImageGenerator.psm1:1502 char:9
>   +         Throw $Strings.ERR_IMAGE_WAS_NOT_PRODUCED
>   +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (The requested i...al information.:String) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : The requested image could not be created. Please consult the command output for addition
>      al information.
>
> PS E:\Nano\NanoServerImageGenerator>

I tried to investigate whats wrong but without success.

Host OS is Windows 10

```
PS E:\Nano\NanoServerImageGenerator> $PSVersionTable

Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.122
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.122
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

So it says it can't find the volume. but the partition variable in the Convert machine file is not null.

What might be the problem ?

Thanks

**EDIT:** Some powershell code

```
switch ($DiskLayout)
            {
                "BIOS"
                {
                    Write-W2VInfo "Initializing disk..."
                    Initialize-Disk -Number $disk.Number -PartitionStyle MBR

                    #
                    # Create the Windows/system partition
                    #
                    Write-W2VInfo "Creating single partition..."
                    $systemPartition = New-Partition -DiskNumber $disk.Number -UseMaximumSize -MbrType IFS -IsActive
                    $windowsPartition = $systemPartition

                    Write-W2VInfo "Formatting windows volume..."
                    **$systemVolume = Format-Volume -Partition $systemPartition -FileSystem NTFS -Force -Confirm:$false**
                    $windowsVolume = $systemVolume
                }
```

The output shows error on the bold line.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a reason, but the only work around I found was to copy the files to a Windows 8.1 VM I had running and run the script from there.  I could not get this script to run on Windows 10 v1511.